# Debug brunch.io with coffee sourcemaps?

Tags: javascript, brunch

I was wondering how to debug my brunch.io (ember) app with sourcemaps?

My sourcemaps are beeing generated by IntelliJ Webstorm – but how do i use these together with the brunch.io build process?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, yet. Source maps have big priority for the next release: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/288.

**edit:** OK, Source maps are in brunch now! Happy debugging.